# Parallelize nested loop in C with openMP

Tags: c, openmp

How can I parallelize the nested loop with statements using an OpenMP in C. I would be thankful to you.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <omp.h>


int main(int argc, char **argv) {
   int n= 10000;
   double y [10000];
   int i;
   int j;
   double t = 0;
   double k, f;
   for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
         k = (double) (i+1);
         f = 0;
         for (j=0;j<n;j++)
              f += k / (double) (j+1);
         t += f;
    }
   printf("%f\n",t);
}
```

Comment: This is not even C. Try writing the single-threaded program correctly first.

Comment: `t +=b;` uses *uninitialised variable*. There is also a syntax error. Please post the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows what you tried.

Comment: @vane. the code is edited. does this work?

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you struggling. This platform works by showing that you have done some research and not just duming code here hoping that someone parallelizes it for you. Read about OpenMP reudction.

Comment: I tried #pragma omp for and schedule(static). even with simple loop I cant see if my program is running on parallel. I am using ubuntu 16.06.

Comment: Try this tutorial https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/openMP/exercise.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `reduction` openmp clause. Here is a short example:

```
#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:f)
for (j=0;j<n;j++)
    f += k / (double) (j+1);
```